# ASP.NET Web-API OWIN: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, owin

Thanks to the help of some users on this site, I got my test application working and am now starting to write the actual application I need.

I have a C# application which uses OWIN to host a ASP.NET Web API. I need the application to supply information about other open applications. I have programmed it nearly exactly the same as my test/example program which I got working, but changed a few names.

When I try to access `http://localhost:9000/api/applications I get an error message:

```
<Error>
  <Message>
    No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9000/api/applications'.
  </Message>
  <MessageDetail>
    No type was found that matches the controller named 'applications'.
  </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

`The Server class is the main class:

```
namespace Server
{
    public class Server
    {
        public const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationManager.getManager().AddApplication(new Application(1, "Chrome", 0.5f));
            ApplicationManager.getManager().AddApplication(new Application(2, "Windows Media Player", 1.0f));
            ApplicationManager.getManager().AddApplication(new Application(3, "Minecraft", 1.0f));

            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is a my Web API config class:

```
namespace Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
namespace Server.Api.Controllers {
    public class ApplicationController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Application> Get()
        {
            return ApplicationManager.getManager().GetApplications();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            Application app = ApplicationManager.getManager().GetApplication(id);
            if (app == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(app);
        }
    } }
```

The Application object just contains a few properties and constructors. The ApplicationManager class just adds applications to a list of applications, which is used by the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `http://localhost:9000/api/applications` by `http://localhost:9000/api/application`. Last letter `s` caused this issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: That fixed the problem. I thought I already tried that but I must have tried with wrong port number or had a typo. Apparently I also can't use constructors in my Application class because it throws a InvalidDataContractException error.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem as well. After struggling a lot I realized that my Controller class was private which was causing the issue.